# Adding the line console.log causes a different return

Tags: javascript

I was doing a kata on code wars and discovered that

```
    function findNextSquare(sq) {
     var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);
     console.log((rt++)**2)
     return rt%1 !== 0 ? -1 : ((rt++)**2); 
    } //>> 144
```

whereas

```
    function findNextSquare(sq) {
     var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);
     //console.log((rt++)**2)
     return rt%1 !== 0 ? -1 : ((rt++)**2); 
    } //>> 121
```

Which is to say that, simply commenting out the console.log causes a different return value...

Also, worth note: the first console logs 121, rather than 144.

Here it is on repl.it: https://repl.it/languages/javascript

I wonder if this has to do with asynchronicity. Can someone explain why removing the console.log changes the return?

Comment: because you are increasing `rt` value in console log by doing `rt++`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `console.log((rt++)**2)` has the *side effect* of increasing `rt` by 1.

Commenting it out obviously has the effect of `rt` being one less, which accounts for the difference between 121 (11 * 11) and 144 (12 * 12).

Answer (score 7):

**Quick solution:**

```
function findNextSquare(sq) {
  var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);
  return rt % 1 !== 0 ? -1 : (rt + 1)**2; 
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

This has nothing to do with asynchronicity.

**`rt++`** in `console.log((rt++)**2)` causes the `rt` variable to be **incremented**. Therefore, `rt` will be different (one more than it should be) when it gets to the `return` line.

Note the difference:

- `rt + 1` is an expression that adds 1 to `rt` and returns the result — `rt` stays unchanged
- `rt++` adds 1 to `rt`, **saves the result back to `rt`**, and returns the **old** `rt`
- `++rt` adds 1 to `rt`, **saves the result back to `rt`**, and returns the **new** `rt`

Let's see what your original code did with **`sq = 16`**, with the `console.log` **not** commented out:

```
function findNextSquare(sq) {            // sq = 16
  var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);                // rt = 4
  console.log((rt++) ** 2);              // logs 4^2 = 16, rt incremented to 5
  return rt % 1 !== 0 ? -1 : (rt++)**2;  // returns 5^2 = 25, rt incremented to 6 (unneeded)
}
```

When you **remove** `console.log`, this is the result:

```
function findNextSquare(sq) {            // sq = 16
  var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);                // rt = 4
  return rt % 1 !== 0 ? -1 : (rt++)**2;  // returns 4^2 = 16, THEN rt is incremented to 5
}
```

The solution is to add 1 to `rt` and then square the **new value**. We don't actually need to save the new value back to `rt`:

```
function findNextSquare(sq) {              // sq = 16
  var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);                  // rt = 4
  return rt % 1 !== 0 ? -1 : (rt + 1)**2;  // returns (4 + 1)^2 = 25
}
```

If you want a `console.log` in there, you can have it, just make sure it does not change `rt`:

```
function findNextSquare(sq) {
  var rt = Math.sqrt(sq);
  console.log((rt + 1) ** 2);
  return rt % 1 !== 0 ? -1 : (rt + 1) ** 2; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `++` operator automatically increments the given variable. And its not just for the `console.log()`.

What happens when you do `variableName++;` is equal to writing

`variableName = variableName + 1;`

so whether you have used the `++` operator inside a `console.log()` or somewhere else, the variable gets incremented for good.

Be careful how you use it. If you want to still use the console log with incremented variable, I would suggest using `console.log(variableName + 1);`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Expression used in `console.log` increments `rt` value.